# How to connect to docker on Azure VM?

Tags: azure, docker, virtual-machine

I have installed a DIGITS docker on my Azure VM. I am trying to connect to this Docker using its IP Address from my local machine (outside the VM). I have not had any success in doing so. Is this even possible? If so, how?

I have the IP Address of the Docker from running `docker inspect <container-ID> | grep IPAddress`. Doing a curl on the obtained IPAddress with the specific port does not connect to the Docker.

Comment: Sounds like Firewall / Azure Network Security Groups? Is the port open and mapped from Container to Host-OS?

Comment: @opHASnoNAME It was a problem with the NSG with the port not being open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Chun-Yen Wang said, you should add the **port** exposed to Azure NSG.
For example, I expose docker on port 5000, add inbound rules via Azure portal like this:

[image]

After that you can use Azure VM's **public IP address** to access it, you can find your public IP address here:

[image]

`curl http://52.168.28.103:5000`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The docker containers on Azure VM can be accessed via the public IP address of the host VM, and the port exposed:

1. Public IP: there should be one when the VM is created.
2. Port: whatever ports the docker container exposes, they need to be opened for web traffic, just like [Create a Linux virtual machine with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-portal), section "Open port 80 for web traffic".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your host/remote machine is running Linux - If you want to access the container (running on a remote server) directly from local machine you should first install SSH Server in the container and map the 22 port of container to a port on host. And then open that host port and protocol TCP (to let SSH) for inbound traffic on NSG in Azure portal (as told by Chun/Jason)